# Regex Token Pattern C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match multiple tokens in html string like the following example. The html string is pulled from the database and replaced with values then sent as email body. The problem with the sample below only matches three tokens. The last line matches from the first start token up to the second end token. Can someone please help.

`\B(<\$%)\w.+(%\$>)\B` OR `(<\$%)\w.+(%\$>)`

```
<div><$%Booking.id%$></div>
<div><$%PropertyUnit.name%$></div>

<div><$%Booking.id%$></div><div><$%PropertyUnit.name%$></div>
```

I've been playing around with the pattern using online tester like http://regexr.com/3dm88

Thanks in advance

Comment: `\B(<\$%)[a-zA-Z\.]+(%\$>)\B` instead of matching a word, just match the letters and the dot

Comment: @tttony Thanks. This seems to work. You should have put it as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\B(<\$%)[a-zA-Z\.]+(%\$>)\B`

Instead of matching a word with `\w`, just match the letters `a-zA-Z` and the dot `\.`